# Flash: viewer for big map

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dictionary

I have a very big map (pixeldata, not vector) and i want to create a viewer in flash that allows to view the map. The map is stored (in some way, to be decided) on a server. Probably the map will be stored in different resolutions on the server. 
The viewer should download the currently needed parts in the proper resolution at the current zoomlevel from the server to display it - similarily to google maps for example.

Now - i already have some ideas on how to do this - but maybe there is already a framework available for exactly this or some good article describing it (client as well as server-vise).

Anyone got a hint?

Comment: Pretty sure Google map API will do what you want.

Comment: but i need it to work with my own image. and parts of the image need to be updated regularily by the server. google map api can do that?

Comment: Well that's why this is a comment and not an answer. I am pretty sure Google maps will allow you to add custom maps/images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using zoomify.
http://www.zoomify.com/

they have a flash library that handles this use case very well.

but never mind that they have not updated their embed codes on the site in a while. (broken in chrome) you can update it with swfobject and be rolling in no time.

Comment: zoomify doesn't seem to be a library that can be well integrated into a bigger application but rather some finished application that can be embedded into a webpage

Comment: did you click the zoomify flash tab? You get embeddable zoomify viewers that you can integrate into your app. The Zoomify Flash Developer (as opposed to Zoomify flash)one includes full source files and API.

Comment: Here is teh purchase link to the zoomify flash developer version for Window http://zoomifycorp.stores.yahoo.net/zoomifwin.html

Answer (score 1):

What about [OpenScales](http://openscales.org/)?  I think it would work for what you need to do.  Take a look and let us know!